# How to get online or offline state of a WCF Service with a WP7 Application

Tags: wcf, windows-phone-7, service

im working on a Windows Phone 7 Application that communicates with a Azure hosted WCF service.

Everything works fine in communication and so on. But i want to handle the situation when the Service is not online.

Now the WP7 App has a main screen with a login. After clicking the "Login" button the Application sends the credentials to the WCF Service which communicates with a Database.

And now my question is, is there a way to get the online/offline state of the WCF Service?
So i could give feedback to the user and the application wouldnt crash (:

Thx alot for any answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just call the service and have some programming logic to handle the response you receive from it.

```
try
{
    callService();
    //proceed with login
}   
catch(Exception)
{   
    handleFailure();
   //display error message here
}
```

In above code if the service is online try block will execute successfully and if service is offline then you can display Error message to user without a crash.

For more you can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2867486/is-there-an-example-of-checking-on-if-a-wcf-service-is-online) similar question.